# metadata.interactions different for different auth tokens for /me requests

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We are seeing strange behavior between our Personal Access Token and the tokens we get from users authorizing in via OAuth.  We are trying to get metadata.interactions via this call:

"https://api.vimeo.com/me?fields=account,bio,created_time,link,location,metadata.connections,metadata.interactions,name,pictures,preferences,uri,websites".

When we use our personal access token, we *do* get interactions.  When we use the actual user authorized token, we *don't* get the interactions in the response for the same `/me?` request authorized as the account owner.  Is this by design?